# Dynamic Loader of Executable in Valgrind Ignoring LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: valgrind

1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/otherRoot/lib/ valgrind myProg
2. chroot /otherRoot valgrind myProg

When running the first command, valgrind gives me errors about a stripped dynamic linker because it apparently is not using the one in /otherRoot/lib.  Using the second command, it finds my the appropriate .so and works.

For reference, I have valgrind installed in the "normal root" and "otherRoot" as well.

Why does valgrind/myProg not search for the .so in /otherRoot/lib first?

Answer (score 0):

> When running the first command, valgrind gives me errors about a stripped dynamic linker because it apparently is not using the one in /otherRoot/lib.

The dynamic loader your program uses doesn't (can't) depend on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, because it is the *kernel* the loads the dynamic loader (and the kernel generally doesn't care about environment variables). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Outside of `chroot`, the "wrong" dynamic loader is used with or without valgrind. You can confirm this by pausing `myProg` and examining `/proc/$PID/maps` for it.